# Karaf custom Feature bundles not getting uninstalled

Tags: apache-karaf, jbossfuse, fuseesb

I am using a custom feature file to deploy multiple features and bundles within my karaf.

My feature.xml file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <features name="MyFeaturesRepo">
      <feature name="example-features-myFeature">
        <feature>activemq-camel</feature>
        <feature>hawtio</feature>
        <feature>cxf</feature>
        <feature>camel-sql</feature>
        <feature>jdbc</feature>
        <feature>jndi</feature>
        <feature>camel-http</feature>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.4</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.8.7</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:jaxen/jaxen/1.1.6</bundle>
      </feature>
    </features>
```

I use the following command to install the feature:

```
`features:addurl file:D:/Softwares/jboss-fuse-6.3.0.redhat-187/MySampleFeatures.xml`

 `features:install example-features-myFeature`
```

My bundles and features get installed in the karaf but when I uninstall the same feature, I nothing happens. All the bundles stay in Active/Created state.

`features:uninstall example-features-myFeature`

Even if I remove the feature url, nothing happens to bundles.
I want all the features/bundles to be removed from karaf when I uninstall my custom feature. Can someone tell if I am missing something here?
I am using Fuse 6.3GA.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `feature:uninstall` command uninstall only the target feature, not the feature dependencies.

The solution for you is to list all features that you would like to uninstall. For example:

`features:uninstall example-features-myFeature camel-http jndi jdbc camel-sql`

There is another catch, a feature can be uninstalled themselves if not used by other feature.

Comment: That's not true anymore with Karaf >= 4.0

Comment: That's true, but he uses Fuse 6.3 which is built on Karaf 2.4.0

Answer (score 1):

The `feature:uninstall` command should remove all your bundles, including the dependencies.  It seems there's a bug. A workaround is the following:

```
feature:repo-add enterprise
feature:repo-add hawtio
feature:repo-add activemq
feature:repo-add camel
feature:repo-add spring-legacy
feature:repo-add file:test.xml

feature:install wrap jdbc shell-compat
feature:install example-features-myFeature
```

That way, the `feature:uninstall example-features-myFeature` will work.

The actual problem is that the `jdbc` feature has 2 prerequisites and they somehow mess the internal state a bit.  Installing the `jdbc` feature before seems to work around the problem.
Please raise a JIRA so that this issue can be fixed.

Comment: Which is fixed by now.